# Особенности синтаксиса Node.js

Tags: node.js

Недавно начал изучать javascript. Может кто нибудь подробно объяснить что происходит в коде ниже. Что такое done, почему null на первом месте? Я так понимаю это какой то стиль принятый именно в Node.js?

```
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
  UserModel.findOne({where: {id}}).then((user) => {
    done(null, user);
    return null;
  });
});
```

Comment: откуда вы код взяли? положите его на место. оставьте пока node.js и продолжите изучать javascript дальше

Comment: Это не столько особенность Node.js, сколько один из общепринятых способов писать асинхронный код. Вот тут можно прочитать необходимый минимум: https://learn.javascript.ru/callbacks

Comment: Синтаксис-то тут при чём? Это просто соглашение о том как использовать callback-функции. Впрочем сечас лучше бы переходить на промисы. https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/control-flow/what-are-callbacks/

Comment: @vsemozhetbuty, именно этой информации не хватало для понимания. Спасибо.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, я так понял, результат асинхронной функции - всегда промис, при колбэке просто неявный и непомеченный как объект Promise, просто суть отложенное действие?

Comment: Лучше не путайте себя и других и не применяйте слово Promise к коллбекам. На каком-то высшем уровне абстракции примерно так и есть. Функция «обещает» вызвать коллбек когда-то в будущем и если случится ошибка, то она будет первым параметром коллбека.